# Multi query in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to develop a page with AngularJS.

I have two tables.

```
Table 1 : StateList  

StateCode   | StateName
-------------------------------
AZ          |  ARIZONA      
CA          |  CALIFORNIA
NY          |  NEW YORK

Table 2: CustomerDetail
Name    |  BornState  | LivingState
-----------------------------------------
Peter   |  AZ         | NY
Bob     |  CA         | AZ
```

Want to display list like this on HTML Page.

```
Customer Name   | Customer BornState    | Customer LivingState
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Peter           | ARIZONA               | New York
Bob             | CALIFORNIA            | ARIZONA
```

Instead of state code, I want to display State Name for each type of state information, e.g BornState and LivingState.
I am able to fetch list from Table 2:CustomerDetail but ***how I can convert state code with state name for each type of state information?***

Thanks in advance

Adding more Details

I have $stateProvider as below

```
.state("customerDetail",{
                        url:"/customer/detail/:customerId",
                        templateUrl:"app/customer/customerDetail.html",
                        controller: "DetailCtrl as vm",
                        resolve: {
                            customer: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
                                return Restangular.one('customer', $stateParams.customerId).get();
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

This give me array like

```
{"customerId":"1","customerName":"Bob","BornState":"CA","LivingState":"AZ"}
```

my state array list is like

```
 [{"Code":"NY","Name":"New York"},{"Code":"AZ","Name":"ARIZONA"},{"Code":"CA","Name":"CALIFORNIA"}]
```

I want to display full state name instead of state code

Comment: you may want to share some code for people to take a look.

Comment: Added in above description. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a plunkr

// EDITED
http://plnkr.co/edit/s1XtDHA3ancyP3ceTxeX?p=preview

In your scope :

```
 $scope.StateList  = {} ;
 //init the $scope.StateList  
 var statList = [{"Code":"NY","Name":"New York"}, {"Code":"AZ","Name":"ARIZONA"},{"Code":"CA","Name":"CALIFORNIA"}];
 for(var i in statList){
   $scope.StateList[statList[i]["Code"]] = statList[i]["Name"];
 }

 $scope.CustomerDetail = [{
    "CustomerName" : "Peter",
    "CustomerBornState" :"AZ",
    "CustomerLivingState" : "NY"
 },{
    "CustomerName" : "Peter",
    "CustomerBornState" :"CA",
    "CustomerLivingState" : "AZ"
 }];
```

and the html :

```
 <table>
 <tr ng-repeat="customer in CustomerDetail">

   <td>
     {{customer.CustomerName}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{StateList[customer.CustomerBornState]}}
   </td>
   <td>
     {{StateList[customer.CustomerLivingState]}}
   </td>
 </tr>
```

---

also you can do it with a cleaner way. In the controller , after you get the data from customerDetail stateProvider, add a field in the $scope.CustomerDetail with the real city name and just display it in the view.

Comment: Tell me if don't work. if it work you can accept this answer .

Comment: its not working my statList is like [{"Code":"NY","Name":"New York"},{"Code":"AZ","Name":"ARIZONA"},{"Code":"CA","Name":"CALIFORNIA"}]

Answer (score 0):

You should really use SQL for this, and JOIN the two tables, but if you want an angular solution, this is it:

In your controller:

```
$scope.cus = [array of customers];
var countries = [array of countries];
$scope.countries = {};
$.each(countries, function(k,v) {
  $scope.countries[v.StateCode] = v.StateName;
});
```

And your HTML table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in cus">
  <td>{{row.name}}</td>
  <td>{{countries[row.BornState]}}</td>
  <td>{{countries[row.LivingState]}}</td>
</tr>
```

All ive done is create a new object to act as a hashtable, in which the fetching takes O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting familiar with [LinqJS](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/).. I've been moving more and more of my application specific model interactions / augmentations to the client.

This could be done very quickly and painlessly with a Join statement.